# Does Vim netrw plugin actually display the content of directory file?

Tags: vim, ext4

`netrw` plugin in `Vim` allows one to see directory files. Fow example here I start `Vim` with `vim .`:

```
" ============================================================================
" Netrw Directory Listing                                        (netrw v155)
"   /root/vim/code/files
"   Sorted by      name
"   Sort sequence: [\/]$,\<core\%(\.\d\+\)\=\>,\.h$,\.c$,\.cpp$,\~\=\*$,*,\.o$,\.obj$,\.info$,\.swp$,\.bak$,\~$
"   Quick Help: <F1>:help  -:go up dir  D:delete  R:rename  s:sort-by  x:special
" ==============================================================================
../                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          
./
letters/
mvc/
.chapters
a.txt
b.txt
mvc_paths.vim
```

Is it really possible for `Vim` to see the content of the directory files?  For example `cat .`, `less .`, `hexdump .`, etc all fail with `. is a directory` error message. Or does `netrw` plugin simply list the content of the directory and thus gives an impression that actual directory file is opened?

Comment: `netrw` simply list the directory and shows you the result nicely formatted. It couldn't do otherwise even if it wanted to, as the exact content of "directory files" as you call them is system-specific.

Comment: Ok. So basically as I said, `netrw` plugin simply gives an impression that it reads a "directory file"?

Comment: Directories have not been files on unix for a long, long time. A very long time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reading a directory does not really happen as a file.  It happens with the `readdr` system call.  See `man 2 readdir` for the old implementation as a pure system call and `man 3 readdir` for the wrapper (please, don't use the old implementation).

Yet, Vim's `netrw` does not perform anything like that.  It simply calls `ls` or performs globbing (read below to understand when it does one and when the other) and parses the output of that.

Configuring `netrw` you have options for how it calls `ls` on **remote systems**.  You can set the listing command in your `vimrc` for SSH and FTP connections as follows (these are the defaults):

```
let g:netrw_list_cmd = 'ssh HOSTNAME ls -Fa'
let g:netrw_ftp_list_cmd = 'ls -lF'
```

(You can even set that to something different from `ls` for FTP systems that do not have `ls`, yes there are some, rare ones, that don't have it.)

For **local listings** `netrw` performs globbing and then calls `getftype()` to decorate the file (`/` for directories, `@` for links, etc.).  In `autoload/netrw.vim` in the `s:LocalListing()` procedure the following is performed:

```
let dirname    = b:netrw_curdir
let dirnamelen = strlen(b:netrw_curdir)
let filelist   = s:NetrwGlob(dirname,"*",0)  " here is the globbing of `*`
let filelist   = filelist + s:NetrwGlob(dirname,".*",0)  " and here `.*`
```

And then `getftype()` is called on every file in in `filelist`.

All in all, `netrw` relies on the fact that Vim has the `glob()` function, and Vim in turn performs a `glob` call (`man 3 glob`).